# Converting Datetime series to string in pandas without looping

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas

I have a datetime series as one column in a Pandas dataframe - **df['timeStamp']**. I want to convert each datetime object in this column into a string. There exists several python functions that converts a single datetime object to string like:

```
str(datetime)
datetime.format(datetime) 
datetime.strftime('%m%d%Y')
```

But to get what I want I would have to loop over the entire column and convert each object to string individually. Something I am trying to avoid. I am wondering if there is any Pandas/Python function to do it in one go. Something opposite of the `to_datetime` function (that converts str to datetime in one go without looping).

Comment: @SDilmac that is for going from string to datetime. The OP wants the opposite

Comment: Its not necessary to give a format to to_datetime function. It works fine for me without giving it a format

Answer (score 5):

You have some options here. First you can do `astype(str)`:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2015-01-01 09:00:00', periods=3))

In [2]: s
Out[2]:
0   2015-01-01 09:00:00
1   2015-01-02 09:00:00
2   2015-01-03 09:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [3]: s.astype(str)
Out[3]:
0    2015-01-01T10:00:00.000000000+0100
1    2015-01-02T10:00:00.000000000+0100
2    2015-01-03T10:00:00.000000000+0100
dtype: object
```

But this will give you the standard numpy representation of the datetime in string format.

Another option where you can control the format is using the `strftime` method in an apply (this would actually be equivalent to writing a loop, but shorter):

```
In [4]: s.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m%d%Y'))
Out[4]:
0    01012015
1    01022015
2    01032015
dtype: object
```

Lastly, in the upcoming 0.17.0 release (the feature is currently in the development version), you will also be able to do:

```
In [5]: s.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
Out[5]:
0    01/01/2015
1    02/01/2015
2    03/01/2015
dtype: object
```